# ValueError in tensorflow,,,

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

> Value Error: Cannot feed value of shape (7800, 28, 28, 1) for Tensor
>   'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(1, 28, 28, ?)'

My Placeholder is looks like this:

```
x1_image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, Size, Size, None])
```

How do I convert (7800, 28, 28, 1) into (1, 28, 28, 7800) in tensor flow ?

Comment: How about defining your placeholder with shape `[None, Size, Size, 1]`, assuming your size is 28?

Comment: Thanks for your kind response.Yes, Size=28,,,I was try like this [None, Size, Size, 1] but not working.

Comment: I verified my approach with some dummy data. Maybe some other part of your code causes the error. Please post a minimal working example of your code. Especially, show us the part where you feed your data to the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Define your placeholder to match the shape of your data:

```
x1_image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, Size, Size, 1])
```

Then you can use [`tf.transpose`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose) to reorder the dimensions:

```
x1_image = tf.transpose(x1_image, (3, 1, 2, 0))  # Now it has shape (1, Size, Size, None)
```

Actually, I am not sure if you would need to reorder the axes with `(3, 1, 2, 0)` or `(3, 2, 1, 0)`, since both of them would have the same shape; the first one would keep axes 1 and 2 in the same place, and the second one would swap them too.

Comment: Thank you so much.I am trying,,,